# Can't insert data in ContentValues

Tags: android

Hello I'm using this code to insert data into my database. In another activity I use a Cursor and I can see the data of table1 or table2 individually. But if I use both I can only see the data of table 2.

When I use the cursors to get the data I see that one is empty. I think I'm not inserting the data correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

//TABLE 1

```
cv.put(idAttendance, 1);
cv.put(attendPlayer, "Tiago");

db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);

    cv.put(idAttendance, 2);
    cv.put(attendPlayer, "Joao");
    db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);


    cv.put(idAttendance, 3);
    cv.put(attendPlayer, "Pedro");

  db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);
```

//TABLE2

```
    cv.put(idTrainInd, 1);
    cv.put(TIindicator, "Remate Sucesso");
    db.insert(TrainingIndicatorTable, idTrainInd, cv);

    cv.put(idTrainInd, 2);
    cv.put(TIindicator, "Remate SEM Sucesso");
    db.insert(TrainingIndicatorTable, idTrainInd, cv);
```

---

Still can't save data.

My Class is something like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private ... // database and tables


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null,33); 


}

SQLiteDatabase db = null;



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


//here i create all tables
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ... ) 


db=this.getWritableDatabase();


//THEN I USE THE CODE OF MY FIRST QUESTION

ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

//TABLE 1
cv.put(idAttendance, 1);
cv.put(attendPlayer, "Tiago");

db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);



cv.put(idAttendance, 2);
cv.put(attendPlayer, "Joao");
db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);


cv.put(idAttendance, 3);
cv.put(attendPlayer, "Pedro");

db.insert(AttendanceTable, idAttendance, cv);


//TABLE2

//TABLE2
cv.put(idTrainInd, 1);
cv.put(TIindicator, "Remate Sucesso");
db.insert(TrainingIndicatorTable, idTrainInd, cv);

cv.put(idTrainInd, 2);
cv.put(TIindicator, "Remate SEM Sucesso");
db.insert(TrainingIndicatorTable, idTrainInd, cv);


//THEN I USE THIS TO RETURN GET THE DATA BUT TABLE TWO IS STILL EMPTY

/**Get all players from local database*/
public Cursor getPlayers() {

 //   db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT player FROM Attendancetabl", null);

    //c.close();
    return c;

}






/**Get all players from local database*/
public Cursor getIndicadors() {

   // db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT indicator FROM TrainingIndicador", null);

    //c.close();


    return c;

}
```

It's the same problem of the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use support code:

```
private void insertData(SQLiteDatabase base, String table, String columnHack, ContentValues values) {
    base.beginTransaction();
    base.insertWithOnConflict(table, columnHack, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    base.setTransactionSuccessful();
    base.endTransaction();
}
```

Then just call instead your db.insert this one code:

```
insertData(db, TrainingIndicatorTable, idTrainInd, cv);
```

Comment: i got this error : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

Answer (score 0):

Piece of code to Content Values insert will be like below.

```
 private ContentValues initialValues;
    initialValues = new ContentValues();                    
                        initialValues.put("User_ID", User_ID);                      
                        initialValues.put("FirstName", FirstName);
                        initialValues.put("LastName", LastName);
                        initialValues.put("UserID",  UserID));
                        initialValues.put("Password",Password1);
                        initialValues.put("Email", Email);
                       mydb.insertTitle(initialValues,"CheckLogin");
```

// this will be  you databse class or method to insert the values.  hope this helps you.

Comment: I will try it thanks, another doubt that i have is if i can have it all the same class. I either see table1 or table2. I´m not having trouble inserting data, that is working, i´m having trouble when using the two tables at the same time

Comment: you can insert to many no of tables . that doesnt problem.. you should close it corectly.